# How do I loop through a dataframe, perform the addition of 3 specific rows, replace those 3 rows with their sum, then repeat every 57 rows?

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataframe:

```
     2020/01/02  2020/02/01  2020/03/01
0   |     10          10          10
1   |     10          10          10
2   |     10          10          10
.......................................
57  |     20          20          20
58  |     20          20          20
59  |     20          20          20   
.......................................
114 |     30          30          30
115 |     30          30          30
116 |     30          30          30
```

I want to add up rows 0, 1 & 2 then replace rows 0, 1 & 2 with their sum so that my new dataframe would look like this:

```
     2020/01/02  2020/02/01  2020/03/01
0   |     30          30          30
.......................................
57  |     20          20          20
58  |     20          20          20
59  |     20          20          20   
.......................................
114 |     30          30          30
115 |     30          30          30
116 |     30          30          30
```

I then want to loop through the dataframe and add up the 3 consecutive rows every 57 rows then replace those 3 rows with their sum so that my resulting dataframe would look like this:

```
     2020/01/02  2020/02/01  2020/03/01
0   |     30          30          30
.......................................
57  |     60          60          60 
.......................................
114 |     90          90          90
```

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can filter each 3 consecutive values by `57` rows and then agreggate `sum` by each 3 rows:

```
np.random.seed(123)

N = 200
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice([3,4,6], size=(N, 3)))

a = np.arange(len(df))

df.index = a // 57
df = df[a % 57 < 3]

df = df.groupby(level=0).sum()
print (df)
    0   1   2
0  18  11  18
1  12  13  18
2  13  13  16
3  10  14  15
```